# How to set ASP.NET Identity IsApproved field

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity

I cannot find a way to setup that `ASP.NET Identity` User Account has been **IsApproved**.

Is it possible to do actually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if "approved" means that the account was confirmed using an email confirmation. [Here is an article on how to setup email confirmation this using ASP.NET Identity](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/10/adding-email-confirmation-to-aspnet.html). If you are speaking of some other approval process then you could take the same approach and change the **IsConfirmed** property to **IsApproved**.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I mean the classic ASP .NET Membership has those fields and many others... Are we loosing them with ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: Yes, you are loosing those fields in ASP.NET Identity. Everything is customized.  The user must inherit from IdentityUser which has the basic properties of user name, password, ID and claims. Everything else is handled by inheriting and extending IdentityUser for your particular security requirements.